# replacing a country within an SQL insert with a list of countries to create multiple inserts

Tags: sql, shell, unix

I have multiple SQL insertions and I am trying to automatically relpicate these with 1 word (the country) changed, populated from a predefined list of words (countries).

`insert into TABLE_1 (FIELD, VALUE, SITE_ID) values('WEBSITE,COUNTRY', 'abc.com,xxx',12345);`

I have a list of countries (about 200) that I wish to replicate into the above insertion (and many other insertions)

So - the result would look like this:

```
insert into TABLE_1 (FIELD, VALUE, SITE_ID) values('WEBSITE,COUNTRY', 'abc.com,United Kingdom',12345);
insert into TABLE_1 (FIELD, VALUE, SITE_ID) values('WEBSITE,COUNTRY', 'abc.com,Sweden',12345);
insert into TABLE_1 (FIELD, VALUE, SITE_ID) values('WEBSITE,COUNTRY', 'abc.com,France',12345);
insert into TABLE_1 (FIELD, VALUE, SITE_ID) values('WEBSITE,COUNTRY', 'abc.com,Germany',12345);
```

...and so on

I have found a shell script to do this for instances of 1 word:
`sed -i 's/old-text/new-text/g' input.txt.`
...but I'm guessing I need some kind of loop to iterate through my list. And I cannot find anything like this out there (anywhere)

Thanks for your help in advance

Comment: There is a possibility to use `INSERT INTO ...(...). SELECT <fieldvaluesstoinsert> ...` to do multiple inserts e.g. from a different table...some colums may be constants, others may be from other tables...

Comment: Is this  a SQL question or a shell question?

Comment: @SalmanA It's a shell question regarding my SQL inserts

Comment: Where/how the list of countries is stored - in a table ? in a file ? Very different approach, depending on this input

Comment: @dash-o I will be working in 1 (or 2) text files. Appx 3k lines - some of which will have the ```xxx``` text that will need to be replaced by the countries. Hope that explains my question a bit better

Comment: Always better to post the input file, (or a small subset) into the question. It will make it easier for SO readers to provide useful input. Why do you need to split the list of counties into two files ?

Comment: @dash-o Understood! I don't need the output in 2 files - I was considering the country list might be in a 2nd (seperate file). But either way the output would be the original list of 3k lines, transformed to contain the updated (and increaserd) SQL insertions. Does that make sense? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Hope below query helps.

```
 select * into #countries --all your countries

  DECLARE @i int = 0
 declare @c varchar(20)
 WHILE @i < 201 
 BEGIN
 SET @c =( select top country_name from #countries order by name desc)
 SET @i = @i + 1
insert into TABLE_1 (FIELD, VALUE, SITE_ID) values('WEBSITE,COUNTRY', 
'abc.com,'+@c,12345);
delete from #countries  where country_name=@c
/* your code*/
END
```

Comment: many thanks for your help here. I am working with a text document with about 3,000 insert statements. Hence my orig question re: a shell/unix script. Will your above solution work on that, do you think? Thanks again...